# Is finding Elements by a custom attribute efficient?

Tags: jsoup

I'm wondering whether a select statement like this would be efficient:

```
elements = document.body().select("[data-custom-attr=blahblah]");
```

Does JSoup create a Map for all element attributes and values so that it can look them up efficiently, or would this involve a traversal of the entire document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, attributes appear to be stored in a `LinkedHashMap` as of [v1.7.2](http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.7.2-sources.jar).

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes:
line 20: private LinkedHashMap<String, Attribute> attributes = null;
line 21: // linked hash map to preserve insertion order.
line 22: // null be default as so many elements have no attributes -- saves a good chunk of memory
```

I'd be remiss if I didn't tell you a good API is supposed to abstract implementation details away from the programmer.  A detail like this isn't supposed to be something most developers are concerned with.  Of course, no harm done if it's just for curiosity's sake.

Comment: Interesting.  Re: abstracting implementation details, the performance characteristics of various API calls can be important.